# Initially opening the third item of a dropdown list and allowing it to close on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a list of dropdown items. They are all closed initially. Clicking on a closed dropdown item opens it. Clicking on an open dropdown item closes it.

(Code simplified for easier reading)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Collapse } from '@blueprintjs/core'
import styles from './a-type.module.scss'

const NudgeTrigger = ({ isShowItem, checkItem, index, title }) => {
  const [toggleArrow, setToggleArrow] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div className={`nudgeTrigger ${toggleArrow ? 'nudgeTriggerUpArrow' : ''}`} onClick={() => {
      // Does the index exist in the showListItem array? Yes: delete it and close dropdown. No: add it and open dropdown.
      isShowItem(index) ? checkItem(index, false) : checkItem(index, true)
      setToggleArrow(!toggleArrow)
    }}>
      <p key={index} className={styles.nudgeTitle}>{title}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const contactCalculator = () => {
  const [showListItem, setShowListItem] = useState([])
  const [nudgeList, setNudgeList] = useState([])

  // dropDown open/close
  const checkItem = (index, value) => {
    if (value) {
      setShowListItem(showListItem => [...showListItem, index])
    } else {
      setShowListItem(showListItem => showListItem.filter(item => item !== index))
    }
  }

  const isShowItem = (index) => {
    if (showListItem.indexOf(index) > -1) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }

  return (
      <div className="contents-width">
        <div id="calculator" className="contents-width">
          {nudgeList.map((nudge, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={index} className={styles.nudgeItem}>
                <NudgeTrigger isShowItem={isShowItem} checkItem={checkItem} index={index} title={nudge.title}/>
                <Collapse isOpen={isShowItem(index)}>
                  <p className={styles.nudgeContent}>{nudge.content}</p>
                </Collapse>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
  )
}

export default contactCalculator
```

The open/close state is managed by the following component

```
<Collapse isOpen={isShowItem(index)}>
```

I want the third dropdown item to be open initially. My first attempt was to edit the following code from

```
  const isShowItem = (index) => {
    if (showListItem.indexOf(index) > -1) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
```

To always make the 2nd index (third item) be open

```
  const isShowItem = (index) => {
    if (showListItem.indexOf(index) > -1) {
      return true
    } else if (index === 2) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
```

But doing this makes the third item always be open. Even if I click on it, it won't close.

How do I make the third dropdown list item be open initially and then make it able to be closed again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by initializing `showListItem` array with index 2.

```
 const [showListItem, setShowListItem] = useState([2])
```

And revert back `isShowItem` function like below:-

```
  const isShowItem = (index) => {
    if (showListItem.indexOf(index) > -1) {
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
```